# Manhwa where a woman is transmigrated into a Boys' Love novel

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, webcomics

I'm looking for a manhwa where the Female Lead (FL) was transmigrated into a Boys' Love (BL) novel, and to protect him she tries to marry him to keep his secret that he will love a guy.

I think the the Male Lead (ML) has white hair and purple eyes and he has a mole next to his eyes, and the FL has bad parents. I vaguely remember her dad tries to get her back to his house and the father of the ML doesn't let her go.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: Did the female lead disguise herself as a man in order to enroll in an all-boys academy?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure its "I'm Engaged to an Obsessive Male Lead".

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain why you think this is the answer (i.e. which details match).